# Only scroll to top of page on certain pages of my Vue.js router - keep scroll position same on other

Tags: javascript, vue.js

On the homepage, I would like to navigate to one of my pages in a new Vue (transitioned) view. 
The user, upon 'closing' this page ends up back to last scrolled position.

That works by adding the Vue native scrollBehavior to the VueRouter.

This is what I've got going there:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
scrollBehavior: (to, from, savedPosition) => new Promise((resolve) => {
    const position = savedPosition || {};
    if (!savedPosition) {
      if (to.hash) {
        position.selector = to.hash;
      }
      if (to.matched.some((m) => m.meta.scrollToTop)) {
        position.x = 0;
        position.y = 0;
      }
    }
    router.app.$root.$once('triggerScroll', () => {
      router.app.$nextTick(() => resolve(position));
    });
  }),
routes, 
[]
```

**However!** That means that scrolling down on the homepage, would result in ending up at the same scroll position on the new page.

I would like to prevent that. That the new page opens at `y = 0`. But! Without resetting the previous scroll position on the homepage.

So when the back button is clicked, it sends the user back to the scroll position of the element clicked on the homepage.

Any idea how I can pull this off?

Answer (score 2):

I have –instead of messing with the scrollbehaviour- added to my Home view component the following:

```
export default {
[..]
  activated() {
    window.scrollTo(0, this.scrollposition);
    console.log("scrolling to this.scrollposition = " + this.scrollposition);
  },
  beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
    this.scrollposition = window.pageYOffset;
    next();
  }
};
```

This saves the position when you leave to another page, and puts the scrollposition back to what it was when the view gets activated again.

On the case study pages themselves, I have added:

```
  activated() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
```

… in order to scroll these to the top when they are 'opened'.

Seems to work flawlessly, cross-platform and in all modern browsers.

Good enough for me. Hope someone else has some use out of this. :)

Comment: I am having this exact issue right now! Visiting another page sometimes causes it to be shown at the same scroll position as the homepage. So a manual force on specific pages would be ideal.

Where is it that you are putting/calling the activated()? I tried in mounted but it only works upon initial load and not revisit.