# How to maintain scroll position in a division after a division is redisplayed in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my Laravel and Vue project, I display posts in a scrollable division. This division is displayed when 'showFeed' is true.

```
 <div v-show="showFeed"  class="scroll-container" v-scroll="handleDebouncedScroll" >
                    <div   class="card mb-4" 
                        v-cloak v-for="(item,index) in posts" 
                                :key="item.id">
                        <div  v-bind:id=index
                            class= "border"
                        >
                                <user-feed-post
                                    ....
                                    :item="item">
                                </user-feed-post>
                        </div>
                    </div>                
                </div>
```

On clicking a post, I display post details on the page in a separate division through a component. This is accomplished by making **showFeed** false and **showPostDetails** true.

```
<div v-if="showPostDetails" >
    <post-details
        ....
     >
          </post-details>    
 </div>
```

When I close the **post-details** component, I make **showPostDetails** false and **showFeed** true. The logic is working, however, there is one issue -- the posts are displayed starting from the first post. In other words, the posts division displays the first post at the top, whereas I might had scrolled to the tenth post when I clicked to display the post details. I have implemented a hack to scroll the division back to the post I clicked (e.g. tenth post), but this does not seems to be a good approach.

Any, suggestion, how to ensure that when the posts division is redisplayed, it maintains its scroll position?

**Update**: I read somewhere that **keep-alive** (with some code) may be used to accomplish what I want to do accomplish. Any one with experience with keep-alive?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Vue Router, you can create a composable that you can wire up to your element where you'd like to persist the scrollbar.  [This example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-psxpjp?file=src%2FApp.vue&terminal=dev) uses a composable in a base wrapper component and in a more complex example, where our view has multiple scrollbars that we'd like to persist.

**scrollPosition.ts**

```
import { onActivated, ref, Ref, unref } from "vue";
import { onBeforeRouteLeave } from "vue-router";

export function useSaveScrollPosition(el: Ref<HTMLElement>) {
  const scrollTop = ref(0);
  const scrollLeft = ref(0);

  onActivated(() => {
    const $el = unref(el);
    if ($el) {
      $el.scrollTop = scrollTop.value;
      $el.scrollLeft = scrollLeft.value;
    }
  });

  onBeforeRouteLeave(() => {
    const $el = unref(el);
    if ($el) {
      scrollTop.value = $el.scrollTop;
      scrollLeft.value = $el.scrollLeft;
    }
  });
}
```

**RouteWrapper.vue**

```
<template>
  <article ref="componentEl">
    <slot />
  </article>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";
import { useSaveScrollPosition } from "../scrollPosition";

const componentEl = ref<HTMLElement>();
useSaveScrollPosition(componentEl);
</script>
```

**ViewHome.vue**

```
<template>
  <RouteWrapper style="height: 100px; overflow: auto">
    <LongContent :total-lines="50" />
  </RouteWrapper>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import RouteWrapper from "./RouteWrapper.vue";
import LongContent from "./LongContent.vue";
</script>
```

**ViewThing.vue**

```
<template>
  <article style="height: 200px; display: flex">
    <button>A button</button>
    <section ref="elementOne" style="overflow: auto; flex: 1 1 0%">
      <LongContent :total-lines="200" />
    </section>
    <section ref="elementTwo" style="overflow: auto; width: 200px">
      <LongContent :total-lines="100" content-style="width: 400px" />
    </section>
  </article>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";
import { useSaveScrollPosition } from "../scrollPosition";
import LongContent from "./LongContent.vue";

const elementOne = ref();
const elementTwo = ref();
useSaveScrollPosition(elementOne);
useSaveScrollPosition(elementTwo);
</script>
```

**router.ts**

```
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from 'vue-router';
import ViewHome from '@/components/ViewHome.vue';
import ViewThing from '@/components/ViewThing.vue';

export const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/home',
      name: 'home',
      component: ViewHome,
    },
    {
      path: '/thing',
      name: 'thing',
      component: ViewThing,
    },
  ],
});
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <main style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
    <nav style="margin-bottom: 1rem">
      <a href="#/home" style="margin-right: 1rem">Home</a>
      <a href="#/thing">Thing</a>
    </nav>
    <RouterView v-slot="{ Component }">
      <KeepAlive>
        <Component :is="Component" />
      </KeepAlive>
    </RouterView>
  </main>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { RouterView } from 'vue-router';
</script>
```

This gives you the flexibility of having a main component that handles base pages as well as at the individual element level, but like I said, it only works with the router because we need to make use of the `onBeforeRouteLeave` hook ([credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60769701/1253609)).  I could not get `onDeactivated` working properly, as the element was already hidden, and scrollTop was 0.

I wanted to use a directive, but the activated/deactivated hooks are [not available](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/2349) right now.

Also good to note that Vue Router has a [scrollBehavior hook](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html#Scroll-Behavior), but it apparently only works on using the browser's back/forward button, which is not always the case in my app.

Comment: I'm trying to use your example, but onActivated and onBeforeRouteLeave are never fired. I tried looking at the example project, but it no longer exists.

Comment: @James I think that was my work account, which I've since deleted.  Give me a little bit to get a new example up.  Sorry about that!

Comment: @James I have updated the link and added the rest of the code to the answer for more clarity.